# How can i send a parameter with space to .net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I would like to receive a long string the contains spaces to my method in my web api

To my understanding i can't send a parameter with white spaces, does it have to be encoded in some way?

EDIT:

My content type is:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I've changed it to several other types but none of them allows me to receive a parameter with + instead of spaces

my post method signature is

```
public HttpResponseMessage EditCommentForExtension(string did, string extention, string comment)
```

Comment: You mentioned it is a POST request. Please can you include an example of the body of the request being sent. We will need to know the content type being specified in the headers and the controller POST method signature.

Comment: As Mark said, the media type you use defines how content should be encoded.  This issue is independent of asp.net Web API.

Comment: OK this is how my request looks like
Accept: text/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: he,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: windows-1255,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

I think the important one is:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

My post method signature is:
public HttpResponseMessage EditCommentForExtension(string did, string extention, string comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that work for me is to add %20 instead of the spaces

Answer (score 2):

Usually, parameters to an HTTP GET request are [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding). This means (among other) that spaces are replaced by "+".

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, it doesn't work.
btw it's a post request

Comment: this should be the answer, the OP needs to URL encode all string parameter values

Answer (score 2):

Using `+` to mean "space" in a URL is an internal convention used by some web sites, but it's not part of the URL encoding standard. If you want to use `+` to means spaces, you are going to have to convert them yourself.

As you discovered, spaces (like everything else that needs encoding) should be encoded with `%XX` where X standards for a hex digit.

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1738.txt

Comment: `+` is only acceptable in querystring values, whereas `%20` can be used in the request path _and_ the querystring. e.g. `http://example.com/folder%20with%20spaces/search?key1=value1%20%with%20spaces&key2=value2+with+spaces`.